# When Is the right time to seek Nationality

Tags: france, citizenship, nigerian-citizens

Am from Nigeria and a refugee in France with 10 years permit.... When is it ok to seek for Nationality... Am spending 5years plus in France now

Answer (score 2):

As a refugee, there is [no duration of residence requirement](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2213). There are a bunch of other conditions, in particular you need to speak some French and have a stable job. If that's not the case, I would recommend working on that first.